# Parsing data fast from text file

Tags: c++, file, parsing, optimization

i read in a full file into a string. This is very quick. (For a example 180Mb file - 2s)
Then i extract some values from the string using >> operator and create several arrays from it and insert the arrays into a struct and add each struct into a vector.

I'm trying to find the bottleneck, because this is very slow (but maybe you cant do anything)

1. is the >> approach fast?

   ```
   string str; // gets filled with the file
   struct A;
   std::vector<A> b; // global variables
   // in the function inside the loop 
   str >> a.val
   A a;
   b.push_back(a);
   ```
2. Does the vector take ownership of the a or does it make a copy? Is a still on the stack? I have about 60.000 structs that get insert into the vector. Is this a fast approach or is there a better one.

Comment: `std::vector` takes a copy of `a`. You can avoid this though, using `std::vector::emplace`.

Comment: In principle your code is fine! Otherwise your question is too broad, sorry! Refer to the available [c++ references](http://en.cppreference.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question** is the >> approach fast?

**Answer** Fast is relative. What do you compare it with?

**Question** Does the vector take ownership of the a or does it make a copy?

**Answer** `std::vector::push_back()` makes a copy of the input object.

**Question** Is a still on the stack?

**Answer** Judging solely by the posted code, yes, both `A` and `b` are on the stack.

**Queston** I have about 60.000 structs that get insert into the vector. Is this a fast approach or is there a better one?

**Answer** You might gain some performance by creating the `b` with the required size and reading the data directly into the objects in `b`.

```
std::vector<A> b(60000);
for ( i = 0; ; ++i /* Use whatever looping construct you can */ )
{
   str >> b[i].val;
}
```

**Update**

If you are able to, writing and reading the data in binary form will be the fastest. Use `std::ostream::write()` to write the data and `std::istream::read()` to read the data.

Answer (score 2):

C I/O will often be faster than C++ I/O. Try parsing chunks of data with fscanf() (see: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) and you'll likely find the C approach runs a lot faster.